# Any set of the real line could be written as unions of sub intervals

Tags: general-topology

Let $0 \leq T_0 < T $ and $A \subset [T_0, T]$ any set that could be open or closed or neither both, is it true  that we can write $A$ as a countable unions of disjoint sub intervals not necessary open nor closed?

Thank you

Comment: What is T here?

Comment: What about the set of irrational numbers in that interval?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Take $A$ as the set of irrational numbers in $[T_0,T]$. This set is uncountable but contains no intervals except the ones of the form $[x,x],x\in A$ which only represent a single point. So you need uncountably many of those.

Comment: very convensive answer, thank you.